# Cancel a PendingIntent with unique ReqestCode

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to cancel a pendingIntent so there remains always only one. My requestCode is either "1" or "2" depending on whether the service is starting or stopping. The PendingIntent for the starting alarm looks like this (the stop is nearly identical):

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Service.class);
i.setAction("start");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, SaveSchedulePrefs.getStartReqCode(context), i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.cancel(pi)
```

the new pendingIntent looks like this:

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mTime, pi);
```

From what I've read, the pendingIntent has to be the exact same in order to be cancelled and the requestCode of 1 should satisfy that need. This may actually be working as intended, but log files from multiple days of the alarm re-triggering show the following for both start/stop alarms (7 occurences each):

```
RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{b216a768 type 0 com.myapp.myRinger}
operation=PendingIntent{b2169318: PendingIntentRecord{b20e5820 com.myapp.myRinger startService}}
  RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{b2172ed0 type 0 com.myapp.myRinger}
operation=PendingIntent{b2172ec0: PendingIntentRecord{b20e6160 com.myapp.myRinger startService}}
  com.myapp.myRinger +856ms running, 14 wakeups:
+759ms 7 wakes 7 alarms: act=stop cmp={com.myapp.myRinger/com.myapp.myRinger.Service}
+758ms 7 wakes 7 alarms: act=start cmp={com.myapp.myRinger/com.myapp.myRinger.Service}
```

Is what I'm seeing in the log a history of the alarms that have already been activated or are none of them getting cancelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your original `PendingIntent` has got ACTION="start" or ACTION="stop". In the code you've posted, the `PendingIntent` doesn't contain an ACTION. In this case it will not match (so it will not cancel the alarm).

In order for the `PendingIntent` to match, the following must match: ACTION, DATA, COMPONENT. Intent extras are not compared and are ignored for matching purposes.

Comment: I've added the following setAction method to the above: `i.setAction("start");`, but I'm still seeing the same log results. So now I have a matching request code and a matching action. Could it be that the log output I'm seeing is normal and the alarms are actually cancelled?

Comment: If you aren't sure if the alarms are going off, add some debug logging to a file when the alarm goes off. Then you'll be sure and you won't have to rely on making assumptions.